# How to move a firestore document from cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have a cloud function which listens for document updates within a collection. If a special field is updated, I want to move this document to another collection.

Can I simply update the location of the document?

Or do I have to write a transaction which contains a get(), write() and delete() of the document, or is there a better solution?

That seems to be a common use case but I cant find any documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firestore currently doesn't offer a "move" operation.  You'll have to do what you proposed in your question: copy the document yourself in a transaction.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase Firestore do not support moving data; Its better to copy to new and delete existing.

If your data is kind of transaction data;

> make sure execute operations in transaction block (delete only when
>   copy is success)

**Also you can ensure using [ .validate() ] delete only if its exist in copied node**