# Move to expired document to another collection in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on online noticeboard app. I have a collection called notices and there is notices with expires date. i want to move them to another collection after the expiration. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no server-side "move" operation in Cloud Firestore. You'll have to read the document, write a copy to its new location, and then delete the original.

If you want to do this atomically, you can do all of these in a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20types%20of,on%20one%20or%20more%20documents.).

Also see:

- [How to move a firestore document from cloud functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910873/how-to-move-a-firestore-document-from-cloud-functions)